# How do I extract a common part of multiple images and put it as a single transparent PNG

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, diff

Similar to this [“Diff” an image using ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132749/diff-an-image-using-imagemagick) but lets say I have 2+ images of different sizes.  Say from a game with multiple screenshots and I just want to extract the "coins" image so I detect it in a tool like Sikuli which accepts a transparent PNG and ignores the transparent areas.

I am thinking it is something with the `compare` tool to create a mask for one of the images then apply the mask using `magick`/`convert` to extract the final PNG.

Say I have three images where each are slightly off...

[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to somehow extract the following from the three images.

[image]

Note I am not really requiring a full imagemagick solution.  I am thinking that the alignment best be done with another tool like Gimp, but I am not sure how to even create a "difference layer" that I can shift around so I can align the images.

Comment: Please explain further or show some examples. I do not understand what you want to do.

Comment: I do not see any automatic easy way to find a common area when they are not aligned. If you know you want the red area and there are no other red areas, you can threshold on red, then use connected components to extract the bounding boxes in each image.

Comment: You could try sliding one image across all possible locations of the other and differencing them at each location then look for black locations - i.e. where the difference is zero. It will be slow and inefficient so you may want to reduce the image sizes first to speed it up. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53391124/2836621 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/27342865/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell yah I didn't think it was something trivial or even possible with image magick from what I saw.  There needs to be some form of "human" to do this work on Gimp/Photoshop.  Sort of making a difference layer and shifting that around manually.  I'll update the OP to indicate that magick is not required,